# Has anyone managed to get Botium working with Cucumber for Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, chatbot, cucumber-java

I've tried my best to get Botium to work with BDD so I can see if its useful but the only BDD example I've come across is this https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-bdd-samples/
But I'm unable to install the dependencies with NPM install so I was wondering if its possible to get Botium to work with cucumber for java on intellij?

I've tried to install botium with the js example but I continue to get errors with NPM

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\sahmed248\\IdeaProjects\\botium-bdd-samples\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\sahmed248\\IdeaProjects\\botium-bdd-samples\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sahmed248\IdeaProjects\botium-bdd-samples\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\sahmed248\IdeaProjects\botium-bdd-samples\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\sahmed248\IdeaProjects\botium-bdd-samples\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sahmed248\IdeaProjects\botium-bdd-samples\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sahmed248\\IdeaProjects\\botium-bdd-samples\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sahmed248\IdeaProjects\botium-bdd-samples\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

If anyone is able to either help me solve the issue with NPM or explain how to use Botium with cucumber for Java that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botium Core is a Node.js library, so using it with Java is tricky, but not impossible: Botium supports a special "Grid mode", where it runs in the background and exposes a HTTP/JSON interface - see [here](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/491671/Botium+Grid) for more info.

For your installation problem, here some hints what you can try - obviously the node-gyp package fails:
* remove the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file and run npm install again
* run "npm install -g node-gyp" with admin privileges
* run "npm install -g windows-build-tools" with admin privileges

(see https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

Comment: Thanks Florian, that solved my issue. When installing node-gyp and window build tools its important to be in the botium-bdd-samples folder with admin privileges.